# How to use Facebook access token to post to a users wall indefinitely

Tags: facebook

I'm using the facebook sdk 2.7 to prompt the user to login in to their facebook account and then to be able to post to their wall from our website. This works fine but each time the user visits the website they need to login again.

I do retrieve the user access token when they login. Can I use this to enable the website to always be able to post to the users wall without them having to log in to facebook each time?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use an "Extended User Token" for that, it is valid for 60 days. Btw, you are not allowed to autopost and the message always must be 100% user generated. So make sure the user approves and writes every single post.

How to create Extended User Tokens is explained in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/